# How can I validate the double quotes of values in a pipe delimited file using Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, double-quotes

I have a pipe delimited file in S3, where rows look like this:

```
123 | "val 2" | "" | """ | | val5
```

I'm reading the bytestream and converting it to a dictionary using csv.DictReader:

```
data_iter = stream_from_s3_utf8(s3_stream)
csv_iter = csv.DictReader(data_iter)
```

When I use packages to convert the contents of a file to python code, these packages (sensibly) infer that double quotes are just an indicator that some value is supposed to be a string, so "val 2" (with literal double quotes in the file) goes into my dictionary as a string value without any quotes. And both an empty value (the fifth value above) and a pair of double quotes (the third value above) go into my dictionary as an empty string. But I need to validate the quoting in my file, so I need access to the literal quotes. (For example, the third value above is not valid, but the fifth is.) Is there any way in Python to read the contents of a file while preserving the quotes?

Comment: Have you tried setting QUOTE_NONE?

Comment: quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE

Comment: @ChristianSloper, yep, passing quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE into csv.DictReader seems to give me the quotes back. If you want to answer, I will accept.

Comment: ok, I answered.  Happy it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control how csv.reader and, by extension, the csv.DictReader handles quoting by passing the `quoting` parameter to its constructor.  The whole range of possibilities is defined in the csv module, but here you need the `csv.QUOTE_NONE`

```
data_iter = stream_from_s3_utf8(s3_stream)
csv_iter = csv.DictReader(data_iter,quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

Answer (score 0):

I know you've found an answer, but here's one that does it from scratch:

```
f = open('filename.foo')
raw = f.read()
f.close()
data = [i.strip() for i in raw.strip('|')]
```